# Will the Logitech Bluetooth Keyboard Case "for ipad2" work with the new ipad?

Tags: bluetooth, ipad

I have an ipad2, and I have this keyboard case: http://www.logitech.com/en-us/1222/8213

Will the "new ipad" fit nicely into this case, physically?
Or, if I get one of the new ipads, will I need to get a keyboard case specifically "for new ipad"?

Comment: Full disclosure, in case it isn't obvious: Part of the incentive behind this question is whether or not I would sell my ipad2 + keyboard-case as a package deal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question *from* the new iPad at the Apple Store. Definitively yes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it fits. I bought the iPad 2 case and it fits my third gen iPad...$20 cheaper too :)

The latest generation iPad is slightly thicker then the iPad 2.

The iPad "2" is 0.34" (8.6 mm) depth
The iPad "3" is 0.37" (9.4 mm) depth

Otherwise they are precisely the same width/height.

While I don't have the case/keyboard you mentioned, it looks like it *may* fit in there. If the case has a solid nook for the iPad to fit into, it likely will get (noticably) tighter - but it entirely depends on how much gap is provided. Obviously since the new iPad hasn't been physically sold yet, there wouldn't be a way to actually test - other then measure with something like a micrometer.

Comment: Well, another factor is if there are buttons or ports in places on the ipad3 that aren't on the ipad2, which would interfere with a "snug fit".

Comment: That is a great point. My understanding is that other then the depth, the external physics are the same (and according to this article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad)